# GitHub desktop stuck on committing

Tags: github, github-desktop

GitHub Desktop is stuck on committing:

[image]

[image]

I have waited for a few hours, and GitHub Desktop is using between one and two cores. The repository is medium size (146.26MB, 400 commits) and the commit affects one file only. I use GitHub Desktop 3.0.11.0 (3b1518a) on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate. Using Git shell works.

What could be the issue?